# Executemany is failing with "Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters"

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to tweak out `INSERT INTO` performance of my python code using `cursor.executemany()`, but I am receiving some errors. 
The code:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="database1",
    user="username1",
    passwd="password1",
    database="dbname"
)

data = [
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
]

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.executemany(query, data)
mydb.commit()
```

According to [the example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html), this should work, however, I am getting errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/filipniko/PycharmProjects/scrape/darwin-scrape/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 308, in _batch_insert
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/Users/filipniko/PycharmProjects/scrape/darwin-scrape/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 632, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbtest.py", line 18, in <module>
    mycursor.executemany(query, data)
  File "/Users/filipniko/PycharmProjects/scrape/darwin-scrape/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 350, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
  File "/Users/filipniko/PycharmProjects/scrape/darwin-scrape/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 329, in _batch_insert
    "Failed executing the operation; %s" % err)

mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters
```

Notes:

- Table is empty
- I am able to add rows using `mycursor.execute` for every item in a list

Table schema looks like this:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I am using wrong dependency, I should use `mySQLdb` instead of `mysql.connector`:

```py
import MySQLdb as my

mydb = my.connect(
    host="database1",
    user="username1",
    passwd="password1",
    database="dbname"
)

data = [
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
]

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.executemany(query, data)
mydb.commit()
```

https://thepythonguru.com/inserting-rows/